# How to add current_user.username to FlaskWTF render_kw placeholder of StringField class?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

This is my current code:

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[Length(max=30)],
                           render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})

    email = EmailField(validators=[Length(max=30)])

    submit = SubmitField("Update")
```

I would like to get the current username displayed as a placeholder. I prefer to avoid using the placeholder in the HTML file in Jinja syntax. I thought the following code would work, but it doesn't.

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[Length(max=30)],
                           render_kw={"placeholder": f"{current_user.username}"})

    email = EmailField(validators=[Length(max=30)])

    submit = SubmitField("Update")
```

After importing current_user object from flask_login, Flask returns this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'